# Cmake-gui is not able to find python3-libraries and install path

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cmake-gui

I have a question about this error in CMake-GUI in window 10. Last Tuesday, I mistakenly installed a package without paying attention to the conda environment I was using, causing conflicts. I couldn't even open conda, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it on drive D (since my current drive C is almost full).

The installation process went smoothly, but now CMake cannot find the python3 of my conda environment opencv_GPU. Even after adding BUILD_opencv_python3 = Yes (reference in: [Cannot install openCV 3.1.0 with python3. CMAKE not including or linking python correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638342/cannot-install-opencv-3-1-0-with-python3-cmake-not-including-or-linking-python)), the Libraries and Install Path in my Python 3 section are blank.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfXb.png)

> Python 3:
>
> Interpreter:  D:/anaconda/envs/opencv_GPU/python.exe (ver 3.8.2)
>
> Libraries:   NO
>
> numpy:      D:/anaconda/envs/opencv_GPU/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include
> (ver 1.24.3)
>
> install path:       -

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I expect that have answer to solve my problem.